# How to include external Javascript in GWT offline application

Tags: javascript, gwt, browser-cache, html5-appcache

I have a GWT (well, GXT) application that uses an external JavaScript library to add functionality to my app. My application must work offline, too, and herein lies my problem.

I am aware that adding files to the public folder will make them accessible by my GWT app, but this will not work in case of offline use. GWT compiles my app to make it available offline without problem, but it doesn't include the external JavaScript library.

So, whenever I work within the application and reach the point where said library is needed, the browser will attempt a GET request because the library hasn't been loaded yet and doesn't remain in the cache of the browser reliably.

Is there a way to add the library to my app so that it will be cached together with my GWT app? The library consists of several folders, JS files, images, CSS, etc. My only idea is to dynamically create an Appcache Manifest that dumps ALL files in the browser cache.. in which case I'm scared of breaking the GWT offline functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can generate a manifest at compile time.  Just use a linker that extends com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.AbstractLinker.

See for example  [this example manifest linker](https://code.google.com/p/gwt2go/source/browse/trunk/gwt2go/src/com/gwt2go/dev/linker/ManifestLinker.java?spec=svn34&r=34)
or see [Writing a GWT Linker](http://jectbd.com/?p=29)
or see [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318240/html5-offline-gwt-app)

I do that to include google fonts and to produce a manifest that will only include files for that specific language permutation.

Comment: Thank you! A Linker was exactly what I was looking for. Needed to tweak my app a bit to have everything included but it works fine as far as I can tell.